# Want to fetch information from a website but it shows "250 forbidden" with Python

Tags: python

I am using Python to fetch the information from a website. The script is quite simple:

```
from urllib2 import *

website='http://www.haodf.com'
web=urlopen(website)
content=web.read()#This makes python visit and fetch the content of the website

print content
```

And returns:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>250 Forbidden</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <h1>250 Forbidden</h1>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Why there is "250 Forbidden" in the content? It seems I can't actually visit the website, though this script works when dealing with other websites such as google.com.

Comment: 250 forbidden? *There is no such status code* in the HTTP standard. Silly website!

Comment: Can you actually access the site manually? Maybe they detect that you're scraping and then send you off to a random error page?

Comment: @MxyL: the site is responding differently to different headers. The error code is borderline ridiculous, breaking by sending a 250 Forbidden status line instead of anything reasonable such as a [403 forbidden response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403).

Comment: @MartijnPieters If they didn't want you to scrape their website there's no reason why they have to be reasonable in their response.

Comment: @MxyL: sure there is. There is such a thing as standards and not breaking tools that may legitimately try to load a page.

Comment: @MxyL Yes this website can be visited via any web browser. I think you are right, this website just prevents people from scraping.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I notice that, it's responding to a different header, and I couldn't find anything about '250 forbidden'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This specific web-site requires `User-Agent` header to be sent with request:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> request = urllib2.Request("http://www.haodf.com", headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36'})
>>> print urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb2312" />
...
```

Or switch to [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) (`User-Agent` is sent by default):

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get('http://www.haodf.com')
>>> response.request.headers
CaseInsensitiveDict({'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, compress', 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.2.1 CPython/2.7.5 Darwin/13.3.0'})

>>> print response.text
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb2312" />
...
```

Comment: It's a difference in headers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yup, looking for defaults that `requests` uses.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it was `User-Agent` header :)

Comment: Thanks! It works! And I have a question about this information fetching: is it a real 'visit' to the website? Because I notice that there is a times-visited calculator in this website and the information fetching doesn't make the number of times visited increase.

Comment: @Skywrath it depends on how the counter is implemented. Probably it doesn't count multiple hits from the same IP address.

Comment: @alecxe The counter does change when I manually refresh the web page.